# css: div с текстом накладываются один на другой, вместо того, чтобы располагаться один под другим

Tags: css, css3, html, position

Приветствую

подскажите в чём может быть проблема:

есть вот такой html код (https://jsfiddle.net/vtfdm2yh/):

```css
.line {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  min-height: 27px;
  margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: orange;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.line>div:first-child:not(:only-child) {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  width: 150px;
  background: red;
}

.line>div:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  width: calc(100% - 150px);
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
  <div>очень длинный текст который займёт несколько строк</div>
  <div>text #2</div>
</div>
<div class="line">
  <div>text #3</div>
  <div>text #4</div>
</div>
```

Ожидал, что будет выглядеть так:

```
текст1-текст2
текст3-текст4
```

Но почему-то происходит наложение одной строки текста (нижней) на другую (верхнюю), хотя должна быть сначала одна строка (верхняя), потом 5px пробел, потом вторая строка (нижняя).

В чем проблема, почему так не выводится?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это реализовано на FLEX-х

```css
.line {
display:flex;
flex-direction:row;

  width: 500px;
  min-height: 27px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
 
  font-size: 18px;
  background: orange;
  border: 1px solid black;
  /*padding чтобы ты видел что родитель растягивается*/
  padding:5px;
}

.line>div:first-child{
  width: 150px;
  background: red;
}

.line>div:last-child {
  width: calc(100% - 150px);
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
  <div>очень длинный текст который займёт несколько строк</div>
  <div>text #2</div>
</div>
<div class="line">
  <div>text #3</div>
  <div>text #4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, мой косяк, я не совсем точно описал.

1) высота родительского блока МИНИМУМ 27px (min-height), т.е. если внутри будут дочерние блоки меньшей высоты, родительский блок все равно должен быть 27px

2) может оказаться, что дочерний блок больше 27px и тогда родительский блок должен быть такой же высоты как и дочерний блок максимальной высоты

3) если в дочернем блоке есть текст, он должен переноситься на следующую строку (т.е. многострочный текст)

4) между последовательными соседними родительскими блоками должен быть промежуток 5px (делалось через margin)

Comment: 5) ВАЖНО!!! (пока вообще не знаю как сделать, так что надеюсь люди подскажут) - если высота дочерних блоков меньше 27px, то выравнивать по вертикали (middle) в родительском блоке, который 27px

Comment: Вот так ты хотел реализовать? посмотри ответ

Comment: И еще, у тебя столько вопросов, а ты даже ни один ответ не принял.. Не красиво оставлять людей без внимания, тебе же помогают... Поверь, я не ради своего ответа пекусь...  А вообще.. Если тебя ответ удовлетворяет, рядом  с ответом есть  галочка серая, которую нажав ты примешь ответ и она станет зеленой...

Comment: Air, да я толком еще форумом пользоваться не умею.
Спасибо за совет

Comment: @Zhihar, я хочу акцентировать твое внимание вот на эту конструкцию селекторов .line>div:first-child:not(:only-child)     это не правильно...  убери это..

Comment: Air, почему не правильно? Это позволяет решить вопрос когда дочерними являются не два div, а только один, который должен иметь тот же стиль, что и последний дочерний элемент

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69160/discussion-between-air-and-zhihar).

Answer (score 2):

Проблема решается, но потребуется 15-20 строк кода. Я бы порекомендовал бы использовать лучше таблицу

```
<table style="width: 135px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 74px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 60px;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 74px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 60px;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Это лишь пример и нуждается в доработке.

Comment: Нет, вопрос именно про изменение только стилей. С изменением структуры html все понятно - тут вопросов бы не возникло. А так непонятно, почему происходит наложение и что с этим делать.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```css
.line {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: orange;
  border: 1px solid black;
  clear:both;
}

.line>div:first-child:not(:only-child) {
  width: 150px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.line>div:last-child {
  width: calc(100% - 150px);
  background: lime;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
  <div>очень длинный текст который займёт несколько строк</div>
  <div>text #2</div>
</div>
<div class="line">
  <div>text #3</div>
  <div>text #4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Дмитрий, действительно 'clear' частично решил проблему (у меня раньше был float, но без clear), потом заменил на position, left, right чтобы избавиться от некоторых проблем.

Но даже твой способ до конца не решил проблему - хотя наложения не происходит, но и пробел в 5px между линиями не появился (задается через margin)

Comment: обновил решение, `margin-bottom` надо установить у дочерних `div`-ов

Comment: Дмитрий! Выглядит почти как задумывалось!!! Спасибо.
НО! есть 1 маленькая ошибка - внутренний div оказывается (когда много текста) по высоте больше, чем родительский div !!!, т.е. если делать задний фон и границы не прозрачными, то это будет видно сразу, т.е. все таки хотелось бы, чтоб внутренние divы были целиком во внешнем

Answer (score 1):

Мммм, так?

```css
.line {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  min-height: 27px;
  margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 0;
  background: orange;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.line>div:first-child:not(:only-child) {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  width: 150px;
  background: red;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:18px;
  vertical-align:top;
}

.line>div:last-child {
  position: relative;
  right: 0px;
  width: calc(100% - 150px);
  background: lime;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:18px;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
  <div>очень длинный текст который займёт несколько строк</div>
  <div>text #2</div>
</div>
<div class="line">
  <div>text #3</div>
  <div>text #4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: все заработало
НО! перестал работать :not(:only-child) (https://jsfiddle.net/4gv351q0/)
А ведь хочу, что если только один дочерний <div>, то он позиционируется справа (тут помогло бы position: absolute, но тогда твое решение перестает работать)

Comment: А если несколько дочерних элементов, тогда что?

Comment: предполагается, что их будет только 2 (1 или 2)

Answer (score 0):

По результатам ответов выделил решения, которые работают

**1) метод, предложенный Air**

использование свойства flex: https://jsfiddle.net/7py3hg7u/

```
.line {
display:flex;
flex-direction:row;

  width: 500px;
  min-height: 27px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;

  font-size: 18px;
  background: orange;
  border: 1px solid black;
  /*padding чтобы ты видел что родитель растягивается*/
  padding:5px;
}

.line>div:first-child{
  width: 150px;
  background: red;
}

.line>div:last-child {
  width: calc(100% - 150px);
  background: lime;
}
```

недостаток метода:

- дочерние элементы занимают 100% высоты от родительского элемента
- свойство flex не полностью поддерживается браузером IE (только 11 версией и то не до конца)

**2) метод, предложенный DaemonHK:**

использование в дочерних div свойства font-size, position, vertical-align, использование в родительском свойства font-size: 0px: https://jsfiddle.net/o88pfdqr/

```
.line {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  min-height: 27px;
  margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 0;
  background: orange;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.line>div:first-child:not(:only-child) {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  width: 150px;
  background: red;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:18px;
  vertical-align:top;
}

.line>div:last-child {
  position: relative;
  right: 0px;
  width: calc(100% - 150px);
  background: lime;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:18px;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

недостаток метода:

- перестало работать выравнивание справа для одного элемента (https://jsfiddle.net/o88pfdqr/1/)
- использование font-size для дочерних элементов и обнуление его для родительского элемента

**3) метод, предложенный Дмитрием Поляниным:**

использование в дочерних элементах flex, а в родительском clear: https://jsfiddle.net/o88pfdqr/4/

```
.line {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: orange;
  border: 1px solid black;
  clear:both;
}

.line>div:first-child:not(:only-child) {
  width: 150px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.line>div:last-child {
  width: calc(100% - 150px);
  background: lime;
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Недостаток метода:

- теряется высота родительского элемента, т.е. дочерний элемент может
  стать больше родительского по высоте

**Общий вывод:**

Наилучший способ, как мне кажется, у AIR, но меня пугает flex своей несовместимостью (надо протестировать), при том, что я реально взаимодействую с людьми у которых чуть ли не IE6 стоит :) (утрирую немного)

**Есть еще одна проблема-вопрос**

Дополнительно я хотел бы обеспечить следующий функционал (тоже только листами стилей без привлечения дополнительных тегов):

если высота дочерних блоков меньше 27px, то выполняется выравнивать дочерних элементов по вертикали (middle) в родительском блоке, который 27px, а если хотя бы 1 дочерний элемент больше по высоте 27px, то выравнивание выполняется по top

Answer (score 0):

Всем еще раз привет. Изучив ответ AIR и прочитав про flex, несколько модифицировал его пример под свои нужны.

В результате получился следующий код: https://jsfiddle.net/zq6vxdf8/

css:

```
.line {
    display:            flex;
    flex-direction:     row-reverse;
    justify-content:    space-between;
    align-items:        flex-start;

    width:              500px;
    min-height:         27px;
    margin:             5px 0px 0px 0px;

    font-size:          18px;
    background:         orange;
    border:             1px solid black;

    /*padding чтобы ты видел что родитель раст¤гиваетс¤*/
    padding:            5px;
}

.line > div {
    line-height:        27px;
}

.line > div:first-child {

    order:              2;
    width:              150px;

    background:         red;
}

.line > div:last-child {
    order:              1;
    width:              calc(100% - 175px);

    background:         lime;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="line">
  <div>очень длинный текст#1 который займЄт несколько строк</div>
  <div>text #2</div>
</div>
<div class="line">
  <div>text #3</div>
  <div>text #4</div>
</div>
<div class="line">
  <div>text #6</div>
</div>
<div class="line">
  <div>очень длинный текст#7 который займЄт несколько строк</div>
  <div>text #8</div>
</div>
```

Тут только один вопрос остался (из статьи):

**Вещи, которые следует помнить**

1. Не следует использовать flexbox там, где в этом нет необходимости.
2. Определение регионов и изменение порядка контента во многих случаях
   все-таки полезно делать зависимым от структуры страницы.
   Продумывайте это.
3. Разберитесь в flexbox и знайте его основы. Так
   намного легче достичь ожидаемого результата.
4. Не забывайте про
   margin-ы. Они учитываются при установке выравнивания по осям. Также
   важно помнить, что margin-ы в flexbox не “коллапсятся”, как это
   происходит в обычном потоке.
5. Значение float у flex-блоков не
   учитывается и не имеет значения. Это, наверно, как-то можно
   использовать для graceful degradation при переходе на flexbox.
6. flexbox очень хорошо подходит для верстки веб-компонентов и
   отдельных частей веб-страниц, но показал себя не с лучшей стороны
   при верстке базовых макетов (расположение article, header, footer,
   navbar и т.п.). Это все еще спорный момент, но эта статья довольно
   убедительно показывает недостатки xanthir.com/blog/b4580

***И встал вопрос - а описанная мной задача вообще требует привлечения flex - т.е. решать ее с помощью flex свойств приемлемо, нет ли минусов, недостатков, ограничений?***